# How to exclude a dependency from a fat-jar dependency

Tags: java, maven

We have a Maven project with dependencies. There is one dependency which is a fat-jar which in turn has dependencies in the META-INF/maven folder. Unfortunately, in that folder is a security risky dependency version which must be replaced and increased. 
How can I do this with my Maven build? Are there any Maven plugins which help to exclude this dependency from the fat-jar dependency?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions ? But be careful, if your fat-jar need something from what you excluded, you will get error.

Comment: I have my doubts that some has packaged parts into `META-INF/maven` cause that is a folder which is generated by default by Maven....apart from that if the dependencies are in a far-jar or shaded-jar you have no choice to remove them ...

Comment: If you have a company Nexus/Artifactory, you can create a new in-house version of the fat jar (something like `1.2.3-fixed`). For that, you download the artifact, manually remove the dangerous dependency and upload it again.